# send ctrl+q to a process in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a script to load .torrent files with rtorrent. I can get them to load fine, but the rtorrent command loads up its console each time. The console can be quit with `ctrl`+`q`. Is there a way I can pipe or send this command to the process when I start it? I've looked at [the documentation](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/User-Guide) and it only lists commands for its console. The help doesn't list anything to avoid starting the console.

The script line is

```
rtorrent file.torrent
```

Comment: Have you already tried to run this in `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: @ott-- No I have not-- not familiar with them. Just `[screen|tmux] rtorrent file.torrent`?

Comment: Get some background (sic) info for these programs before using them, like `man screen` or `man tmux`.

Comment: Now I can't make sense of your question.  Pressing ctrl-q causes the program to shut down and stop the download.  You don't want that do you?

Comment: Well, what actually happens is that it closes _that_ terminal app, but any other instance will have picked it up, because there's actually a daemon in the background. So I was confusing myself when I was developing my script, because when I killed instances of the terminal app, other instances would go on happily downloading. I _do_ want to kill new instances, all except the last one running. I've asked to have this question closed, because I don't think it's useful for anyone else. I got things working with deluge.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what kind of terminal you are talking about.  Gnome-terminal does not have such a keybinding by default, but whatever you are using, it should have a preferences menu where you can edit the keybindings and disable this ctrl-q behavior and then it should function normally.

Comment: I am using the default one that comes with Mate, but I want a script that I can run from cron. I guess that would be a bash script?

Comment: @user394, so the part about the terminal intercepting it was irrelevant?  You should update your question to just mention you want to automatically feed that input from a script instead of having to type it.

Comment: The word 'terminal' doesn't appear in my question. The rtorrent program starts up a console, if that's what you mean, which is its own live ncurses screen, like midnight commander, etc.

Comment: @user394, ahh, I see now.  Console and Terminal are synonyms, so it sounded like you were saying the terminal closes when you want they key to go to the program.

Comment: oh, I guess I need to learn more about linux names. Is there a general term for a command-line program that does its own 'console' with a shell?

Comment: @user394, a "full screen" terminal application, or often times they are known by the name of the library that most use for that purpose: "curses" applications.  Technically "console" in unix means *the* terminal that is directly connected to the machine and to which root is allowed to log in on, as opposed to the many serial terminals systems used to have, but this usage is a bit anachronistic these days so it is often generalized to any terminal.